# Modal not reading $scope input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following in my application:

**Index.html**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="company_setup.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="newWidget">Please enter your company id</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" ng-controller="CacheListController">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputType">Company Id</label>

                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="inputType" ng-model="company_id" placeholder="Company Id">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="choice('tryToSetCompany')">OK</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

The problem simply is that when you enter the `company_id` into the input box hit ok the response from Restangular is: `GET https://www.bookingbug.com/api/v1/company/undefined 403 (Forbidden)` my understanding of this is that the `$scope.company_id` is not being read. Is this simply due to a new `$scope` is being set in my Dialogcontroller

Update:

```
$scope.tryToSetCompany = function() {
  var response;
  response = Restangular.oneUrl('bookingbug', 'https://www.somesite.com/api/v1/company/' + $scope.company_id).get();
  if (response.status !== 200) {
     $scope.company = {
      comapny_id: null
    };
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bbPlnkr.controller('DialogController', function($scope, Snippet, $rootScope, $modalInstance, Restangular) 
{ $scope.cancel = function() { return $modalInstance.dismiss("cancel"); };
 return 
$scope.choice = function(action) { return $modalInstance.close(action); };
 }
)
```

There is an extra return between $scope.cancel and $scope.choice, most probably, $scope.choice is not defined

Comment: It isn't because of the extra `return`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$scope.company= {
    company_id: null
}
```

And In `HTML`

```
ng-model="company.company_id"
```

Comment: Did try this and still got the same response when I entered the `company_id`. GET https://www.somesite.com/api/v1/company/undefined 403 (Forbidden). The problem **is** not my Restangular call. It simply is not reading in the `ng-model="company.company_id"`